# tapply returning NA despite na.rm=T being in the argument

Tags: r, tapply

I would like to generate a summary(mean) 0f a subgroup of a dataset in R using the tapply function. The dataset= VehicleData". I would like to calculate the mean for the response variable,"HWY_MPG" after the data has been grouped into 2 factors; "Type" and "Drive". There are some missing data in the dataset, hence I used na.rm=T as part of my argument. However, after I applying the function, Nas were stil returned. Please how do I go about this?

```
tapply(VehicleData$HWY_MPG,list(VehicleData$Type,VehicleData$Drive),mean,na.rm=T)
                4wd    Front     Rear
Car        25.17382 30.68226 24.37903
Minivan    23.26471 24.28902       NA
Pickup     18.82911       NA 21.21270
St.Wagon   26.46635 29.86416 25.61538
SUV        20.60339 26.55390 20.51227
Two_Seater 18.55882 50.26316 24.56571
Van        17.66667       NA 18.38991
```

Comment: I guess it's totally correct. Apparently, there isn't any combination of (for instance) `Pickup` and `Front` in the dataset, so you receive a `NA` value.

Comment: @Nicola, thanks! There wasn't any combination for those combination as you rightly said.

Answer (score 0):

tapply works best with `na.rm=TRUE`. `na.rm=T` doesn't work

try the following..

```
tapply(VehicleData$HWY_MPG,list(VehicleData$Type,VehicleData$Drive),mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```